# nodejs performance timerify return instance instead of number

Tags: node.js, performance

I was expected the timerify function to return a number,
but instead I got a function instance, with node v16.5.0:

```
function someFunction() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
const perf = performance.timerify(someFunction);

const result = perf();
console.log(result);
```

result:

```
someFunction {}
```

Comment: The official documentation includes a code snippet demonstrating correct use: https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#performancetimerifyfn-options

Answer (score 2):

```
const { performance, PerformanceObserver } = require("perf_hooks");

function someFunction() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

const perf = performance.timerify(someFunction);

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  console.log('duration :: ', list.getEntries()[0].duration);

  performance.clearMarks();
  obs.disconnect();
});
obs.observe({ entryTypes: ["function"] });

// A performance timeline entry will be created
const result = perf();
console.log('result :: ',result);
```